# How to add Undefined checks using Lodash?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, reactjs

Whenever we get the nested objects from the response, then we have to traverse to that property and display the values in UI. If suppose i have nested object as below:

```
obj = {
    parent: {
      innerchild1: {
         innerchild2:{
             displayText: "hey i am here"
         }
      }
    }    
  }  
console.log(obj.parent.innerchild1.innerchild2.displayText)
```

and we get error in above the reponse say for example:

```
 obj = {
    parent: {
      error: "error in inner child"
    }    
  }
```

then in this case we will get error for the above console. In order to handle that above error i used && to check for those undefined like below

```
console.log(obj.parent && obj.parent.innerchild1 &&obj.parent.innerchild1.innerchild2 && obj.parent.innerchild1.innerchild2.displayText)
```

As you see this code will get bigger and bigger if we have more nested objects and also maintainability of this code is little difficult. Can anyone help me out how to improvise the above code for undefined checks in nested objects?

Answer (score 0):

I have used lodash get method in order to get those complexity in the code

```
_.get(obj ,'parent.innerchild1.innerchild2.displayText')
```

Its working for me and is there any other way to fix the above problem

Answer (score 0):

console.log(obj?.parent?.innerchild1?.innerchild2?.displayText) you can try it like this using javascript